# Reverse-engineering what is causing floating children to break

Tags: html, css, css-float

Nevermind the award-winning title.

In a brutally large project, a literal mess, deep in the recesses of a very badly structured HTML environment, there are a few containers in which i use a classic floating `div` situation:

**HTML**

```
<div class="floatSet clearfix">
    <div>
       <img src="/thumbnail.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
       I am a label
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.floatSet > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Usually, being a block element, my `.floatSet` would stretch to 100%. The two floats within would then float next to each other neatly. The second `div` (the label), however, once there is too much text, breaks **below** the first `div` (the thumbnail), **even** when there would be enough space to show the whole thing next to it, by simply breaking the text into multiple lines.

I have no idea why. I checked for `white-space: nowrap` and family, but didn't find anybody. I also tried to look down the CSS inheritance tree in Chrome Developer Tools, so that i would understand why the containers are behaving like this.

So the question becomes: what kind of styling (or call it *setup*) would cause floats in my containers to no longer behave as they would do outside?

Something tells me the solution is hilariously simple ..

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show what is happening?

Comment: I wish. Posting 6000 lines of CSS code and a structure nested into almost infinity would not be a great motivator for anyone reading this question to investigate the matter. Rest assured it would not be very helpful. This question is clearly for CSS wizards who have encountered this behaviour, who know what it is and how to fix it.

Comment: I think you did not get the "fiddle" part: Put it in jsfiddle.net, That way the browser can figure out the rest: I think nobody will fix your real underlying problem, but will fix the end result (giving you the handle to fix the underlying problem with a bit of elbow grease).

Comment: Yes, i speak of posting 6000 lines of CSS code into a fiddle. Including privacy issues. I wish i could, but this is not an option. I will have to rely on my luck to reach someone with that question, who just happens to know.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Create another kind of demo?

Comment: This is just the expected behavior of floats. The computed width of the second div (the label) is calculated by its content. When the content is large enough to expand the element to the whole horizontal space, there would be no room for being in-line with other floats. What is the exact desired goal you are looking for?

Comment: I also want to add that this is because line-boxes within floats do NOT wrap other floats (unlike line-boxes of non-replaced block-level elements).

Comment: That's kind of strange to hear, as i have been using this method (perhaps wrongly) for many, many years. The goal is to have the second `div` float on the right side of the first `div` and to **not** have the second `div`s text break so that it falls below the first `div` and loses its margin (which would be the case if only the first `div` were a floater).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `float` with a value other than `none` establishes a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) in which the outer left/right margins of the box doesn't touch the left/right edge of the it's containing block in the presence of floats anymore.

Therefore the box — that is floated itself — is shifted downward until either it fits or there are no more floats present. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats

---

Possible approach to overcome this problem are:

- setting a specific width to the second div and floating that to a side.
- avoid floating the second div and giving a left margin — as the width of the width of the first div — to it.
- Establishing a [new block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) by the second div simply by giving an `overflow` of `hidden` (anything other than `visible`) to it. So that the edges of the box won't overlap the floats.

```css
.floatSet > div:first-of-type {
    float: left;
}

.floatSet > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: gold;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="floatSet clearfix">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    </div>
    <div>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius maxime corporis fuga odit saepe nesciunt facere consectetur voluptates ipsa ducimus? Quidem expedita doloribus blanditiis maiores voluptatem tenetur placeat fugiat beatae.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus nisi suscipit quaerat qui veniam quos inventore laudantium necessitatibus saepe odit odio aspernatur veritatis porro magnam enim ad expedita rerum ex.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et recusandae quos pariatur quod molestias omnis nulla. Cumque eos facere doloremque culpa praesentium ad illum laborum velit ducimus dicta vero asperiores!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a max/min width, and make sure your content fits into it. Once you've done that, you can use `floatset` to float your div's to the left. Also, set your `overflow` to hidden and see what that does.

Comment: I cannot set a width in this situation. Unfortunately it must stay fully dynamic. Not even a %-tage will work.

Comment: Even in responsive code, there's a max and min width to make sure things behave has intended.

Comment: But there's no point doing this in the (very messy) structure i am working on. Thank you for the input, but it is not the approach i am looking for. The containers behave differently in different parental environments, thus there is some underlying, inherited box-model related issue that screams for attention. This is what i am looking for.

Comment: Can I have a link or see a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?